# How can I use hitTest to get underlying views if they are in a table?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, hittest

This code help me get the views beneath the main view:

```
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

         let location = touches.first!.locationInView(self.view)

         let view = self.view.hitTest(location, withEvent: event)

         print("View: %@", NSStringFromClass((view?.classForCoder)!))
}
```

Is there some way to do this for a table?  I have a table with cells and I want to see which cell the user is dragging over, or which view within the cell. My goal is to use a button to disable scroll, then be able to drag over the table and print out the cell or view within the cell as the user drags over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the `UITableView` for the `index-path` based on cell subviews.

```
let point = cellSubView.convertPoint(cellSubView.bounds.origin, toView: tableView)
let index = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
```

`indexPathForRowAtPoint()` returns nil if point is outside of any row in the table

**EDIT**: to handle the touches on the tableView you have to set a gesture recognizer on it.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapOnTableView(_:)))
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

func didTapOnTableView(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let touchPoint = gesture.locationInView(tableView)
    let index = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touchPoint)

    ...
}
```

Comment: do i put that in touches moved in the view controller?

Comment: You need to set a `UIGestureRecognizer` on your tableView and handle the touch down on the target method.

Comment: Yes amazing.  I was really struggling with this.  If you want to check out my other questions they are quite similar as I am trying to eventually get a variable from each cell, instead of just the index.  Each cell has an ID within the uitableviewcell class and I want to try to display it, the way I can display the index now with this answer.  TY so much!